# dependancy between 3 variables in real time embedded c code

Tags: c, image-processing, arm, embedded

hello everyone i performed rgb to grayscale image transformation with fixed point arithmetic on zynq7000 microcontroller and the opperations was faster,now i want to have a threshold of time and perform fixed point arithmetic(reduced precision) or floating point arithmetic(high precision) based on time that i have left.
for example:
if i perform rgb to grayscale with high precision it takes for the cpu 10 seconds.
if i perform rgb to grayscale with low precision it takes for the cpu 5 seconds.
but if the time that i can spend on the task is 7.5 seconds how i will say that i want half of the image to be performed with high precision and the other half with low precition?
i am seeking for a formula that will see my time threshold and will  calculate how many values of the image i need to transform to grayscale with high precisionand how many values of the image with low precsion based on that threshold of time!thnx

Comment: What conversion formula are you using ? How did you implement the low-precision version ? What is precision required ? What is the image depth ? Do you really expect us to guess ?

Comment: How is the title in relation to the question ??

Answer (score 0):

The formula follows from the equation

```
h 10 + (1 - h) 5 = 7.5
```

where `h` is the fraction at high speed (here 50%).

Answer (score 0):

Being

```
nH -> number of high precision images
nL -> number of low precision images
uH -> time to process a high precision image
uL -> time to process a low precision image
T -> available time
N -> images to process
```

To process all the images in less than T:

```
nH * uH + nL * uL < T
```

Where high precision plus low precision is equal to all the images to process:

```
nH + nL = N
```

Substituting:

```
nH < (T- (uL * N))/(uH - uL);

nL = N - nH;
```